# Regex to match 12-length words with exact 1 capital letter, exact 1 digit and exact 10 lowercase letters

Tags: regex

I'm looking for a regex that will match 12-length words with exact 1 capital letter, exact 1 digit and exact 10 lowercase letters.

For example:

```
A5abcdefghij - match

dasdaA4avxsa - match

AA5sssaaaaaa - no match

A55asdasdasa - no match

ab5DaeFsasfg - no match
```

`\A(?=\S*?[A-Z])(?=\S*?[0-9])\S{12,12}\z`

This regex finds all 12-length words that have at least one upper case letter and one digit.

I need regex that matches exactly 1 digit and 1 capital letter and 10 lowercase letters.

Comment: Could it be acceptable to use multiple more comprehensible regular expressions? Also, what programming language are you targeting?

Comment: Why does it have to be a regex?

Answer (score 1):

You may use this regex with 2 lookahead consitions:

```
^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)(?=[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/mxKyPP/5)

**RegEx Details:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)`: Lookahead to assert there is just one uppercase letter in input
- `(?=[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$)`: Lookahead to assert there is just one digit in input
- `[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}`: Match 12 characters of letters of digits
- `$`: End

---

Note that this regex is for matching one single line. If OP wants to match many lines in a document or file then one simply needs to add `\n` in the character class:

```
^(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z][^A-Z\n]*$)(?=[^0-9\n]*[0-9][^0-9\n]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$
```

Comment: Matches strings of any length as long as they have at least one capital letter and one number, and (more dangerously) the use of negated character classes lets this regex [match across lines.](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) See [here](https://regex101.com/r/mxKyPP/4).

Comment: Thanks, you are right that I overlooked length requirement. It is fixed now. Audi note that this reged is for matching one single line. If OP wants to match many lines in a document or file then one needs to add \n in the character class

Comment: According to https://regex101.com/r/mxKyPP/6 your regex is matching across multiple lines, even if it's not supposed to.

Comment: Did you miss second part of of my comment above which says **note that this regex is for matching one single line. If OP wants to match many lines in a document or file then one needs to add \n in the character class**

Comment: Your regex is *supposed* to match only one single line, but since you use negated character classes, the actual behavior is that it can - and does, if you check the example I included - match across multiple lines.

Comment: Ironically, the `\n` in your negated character class **prevented your regex from matching across lines.** Try checking out the examples I've been posting - here's one for your edited regex that shows it *not* matching multilines. https://regex101.com/r/mxKyPP/7

Comment: Indeed - and the one I posted before incorrectly matches across multi lines. As I said, adding `\n` fixed the multi line issue.

Comment: And that's what I had posted more than 20 minutes ago that just by adding `\n` takes care of that requirement even though that is not even OP's requirement.

Comment: `^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z][^A-Z]*$)(?=[^0-9]*[0-9][^0-9]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$` will match across lines and `^(?=[^A-Z\n]*[A-Z][^A-Z\n]*$)(?=[^0-9\n]*[0-9][^0-9\n]*$)[a-zA-Z0-9]{12}$` will not - I think you've got them.backwards in the answer.

Comment: Now I have to ask this. **match across lines** Do you see that anywhere in question?

Comment: I do not, which is exactly why I wanted to point out that your original answer *does* match across lines - OP might not want that.

Comment: *OP might not want that* is your assumption of something that is not asked in question.

Comment: You're probably right. I got concerned at *a regex that will match 12-length words* - "words" don't split lines as far as I know, but I'll take your word for it.

Answer (score 1):

`(?=\b.{12}\b)(?=\b[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*\b)(?=\b[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*\b)\b\w{12}\b`

This regex asserts there are exactly 12 characters in the word, asserts there is exactly 1 uppercase letter, and asserts there is exactly 1 lowercase letter.

```regex
BREAKDOWN

(?=\b.{12}\b)

(?=         )   assert the following is true for the word ahead:
   \b     \b    between the start and the end of the word...
     .          ...any character except newline may appear...
      {12}      ...but there must be 12 characters


(?=\b[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*\b)

(?=                           )   assert the following is true for the word ahead:
   \b                       \b    between the beginning and end of the word...
     [a-z0-9]*     [a-z0-9]*      allow any number of lowercase letters or numbers to appear before or after...
              [A-Z]               ...exactly one capital letter


(?=\b[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*\b)

(?=                           )   assert the following is true for the word ahead:
   \b                       \b    between the beginning and end of the word...
     [a-zA-Z]*     [a-zA-Z]*      allow any number of lowercase or uppercase letters to appear before or after...
              [0-9]               ...exactly one number


\b\w{12}\b

\b      \b   between the beginning and the end of the word...
  \w         let a word character a-z, A-Z, 0-9, or _ appear
    {12}     exactly 12 times (redundant but included here for clarity)
```

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/T1bPeX/6/)

The "exactly one number" and "exactly one capital letter" checks mutually assure that even if one of them allows multiple numbers or capital letters, the other does not.

**Do not use negated character classes `[^ ]` when trying to match between `^` and `$` or `\b` for a single-line or single-word match.** Unlike `.`, negated character classes include `\n`: they can and gladly will skip through multiple lines to find their match, ignoring `^`, `$`, and `\b`.

---

EDIT: as stated in the comments, OP is trying to generate strings that match the regex. This is a much more efficient way to do that.

```py
import random

#seed the RNG with system time
random.seed(None)

#all the characters we'll be using
lowers = 'qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm'
uppers = 'QWERTYUIOPASDFGHJKLZXCVBNM'
number = '0123456789'

#how long the generated string will be - change this as you wish
length = 12

#repeat until CTRL-C
while True:
  #get a random position for the uppercase letter
  uprspot = random.randint(0, length-1)
  numspot = uprspot

  while uprspot == numspot:
    #get a random position for the number that ISN'T the upper letter's space
    numspot = random.randint(0, length-1)

  strgen = ""

  #generate the string
  for i in range (0, length):
    #check if it's time to print the uppercase letter
    if i == uprspot:
      strgen += random.choice(uppers)

    #check if it's time to print the number
    elif i == numspot:
      strgen += random.choice(number)

    #neither - print a lowercase letter
    else:
      strgen += random.choice(lowers)

  #prints to STDOUT - feel free to redirect this to a file
  print(strgen)
```

Comment: Any idea how to use it to generate all possible words that meet this regex? I thought it will work with exrex library in Python, but unfortunately this library doesn't work properly with this regex, even though regex itself is correct.

Comment: @aster Python regex syntax can be slightly different from other regex, so it's possible the expression needs translation. What specifically is going wrong with the regex / with python? Do you have an error message? Also, regex is usually used to find strings, not generate them - you may find some difficulty there.

Comment: It's doesn't return any error. It works but generates also combinations that don't meet the regex requirements like for example:

[1] "            A0EYG"
[1] "            A0EYH"
[1] "            A0EYI"
[1] "            A0EYJ"
[1] "            A0EYK"
[1] "            A0EYL"
[1] "            A0EYM"
[1] "            A0EYN"
[1] "            A0EYO"

import exrex

g = generate('(?=\b.{12}\b)(?=\b[a-z0-9]*[A-Z][a-z0-9]*\b)(?=\b[a-zA-Z]*[0-9][a-zA-Z]*\b)\b\w{12}\b')

def generator():
  return(next(g)) 


library
https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex

Comment: @aster if you are using python why do you need regex

Comment: It's important to explain in the original question that you're planning to generate string with regex (already a rather difficult thing to do), and to give information about what libraries you're planning to use as well. Exrex does not support the `\w` character, nor does it support a variety of other important characters needed for your question. It's also important to note there's more than 95 quadrillion possible combinations - I think it would be easier to just generate a python string of 12 lowercase characters, and then randomly replace one with a number and another with a letter.

Comment: `(?=\b.{12}\b)` is redundant in regex

Comment: I thought that the way with regex will be quite computationally efficient, I care about the efficiency in generating all possible words that meet the condition of this regex. I don't know how to do it in Python in any other way than filtering out wrong words but it's not very efficient.

Comment: @aster You're quite right; generating all words and filtering out the wrong ones is VERY inefficient. I'll edit my answer with a python program to generate the strings you want.

Comment: @aster See my edited answer. Please remember to accept it if it answers your question, and please also edit the original question to state you're trying to generate strings that match a regex. This helps future developers who see your question understand the context.

Comment: Will this code generate all possible combinations? Some condition is needed to interrupt the loop after all combinations have been generated.

Comment: @aster There's well over 100 billion billion possible combinations based on the criteria you described, and storing them would take about 100 million GB. While this code will technically generate all of them eventually, it's impossible to store them all. Why do you need *all* possible combinations? Maybe there's a better solution available depending on what your program is supposed to be doing.

Comment: How you counted it? I thought it will be much less, about 20 gigabytes somewhere.

Comment: Suppose we have one lowercase letter: there's 26 possibilities, `a-z`. If we add another lowercase letter, there's `26 * 26` possibilities, `aa-az, ba-bz [...] za-zz`. For 12 letters, *even if we ignore the numbers and uppercase letters,* we have `26 * 26 * 26 * [9 more "* 26"]` possibilities, or `26^12`. If we include uppercase letters and numbers, the possibilities are even greater.